# how to hide price in algolia search when not login

Tags: magento2, algolia-search

I want hide price and change to Login to see pricing
[image: design]

[image: my project]

and I want to get sku in to Product code?

Comment: Have you used any extension for this?

Comment: i create custom module now to check login